# Crashes on ResponseSerialization.swift (partial apply for specialized)

Tags: json, swift, crash, alamofire, response

I'm getting this error at Fabric:
***ResponseSerialization.swift line 167***
partial apply for specialized

I think this is related to the fact that the JSON which is returned to me is in a different format. But how do I solve it anyway?

This is Fabric Crashlytics screen:
[image: Fabric screen]

Line 300 is down, but there's no connection there. I guess it's a problem because there's no error here.

```
ApiManager.sharedInstance.makeRequest(urlString: url, params: nil, success: { (responseString) in
        guard let response = Model(JSONString: responseString) else {
            self.noResult()
            return
        }
     ...
}, errors: { (errorCode) in // ERROR LINE (Line 300)
    self.noResult(errorCode)
})
```

I also looked at the same error in Window> Organizer> Crashes in xCode. These are my codes and error lines screens:
[image]

[image]

> I also tried try-catch but it did not work because the code did not
>   fall into error.

**This is my simplified request code:**

*AFManager =   Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration) //Defined in AppDelegate.*

```
class ApiManager{
    static let sharedInstance = ApiManager()

    func makeRequest(urlString: String, params: Parameters!, success: @escaping (_ responseObject:String)->() = { _ in }, errors: @escaping (_ errorMessage:String)->() = { _ in } ){

        AFManager.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: params, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                        switch(status){
                        case 200:

                            guard let response_data = response.data else {
                                errors("\(status)")
                                return
                            }
                            guard let utf8Text = String(data: response_data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                                errors("\(status)")
                                return
                            }
                            success(utf8Text) // ERROR LINE

                            break
                        default:
                            errors("\(status)")

                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    errors(String(error._code))
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**Alamofire / ResponseSerialization.swift:** https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ResponseSerialization.swift

Comment: Can you post your actual code instead of screenshots?

Comment: @SirCJ Ok, I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crash was in a completely different place. The fabric error line is showing in the wrong place. Fabric shows the crash on line **300**, but it's actually line **272**

[image]

```
var coordinate = response.coordinates[0] // Line 272
```

Here are the codes from the failing class:

```
ApiManager.sharedInstance.makeRequest(urlString: url, params: nil, success: { (responseString) in
     guard let response = Model(JSONString: responseString) else {
         self.noResult()
         return
     }
     var coordinate = response.coordinates[0] // ACTUALLY ERROR LINE (Line 272)
     ...
}, errors: { (errorCode) in // FABRIC ERROR LINE (Line 300)
    self.noResult(errorCode)
})
```